# typescript, import * as, no index signature with bracket property accessor

Tags: typescript

I'm new to typescript. I have a large program I am converting from javascript. I'm going through the errors and adding types but I can't figure out how to fix this one.

myModule.ts

```
export const foo = { ... }
export const bar = { ... }
```

myFile.ts

```
import * as myModule from './myModule'

function doesSomething(input: string) {
    return myModule[input]
}
```

Typescript compiler error: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type 'typeof "./myModule"' has no index signature.

I have tried declaring a module and a namespace or trying to implement an interface, but doesn't seem to work. I think the solution is to declare module in a separate file but I can't seem to get TS to recognize it. This is what I would think would work:

myModule.d.ts

```
interface MyModule {
    [key: string]: any
}

declare module 'myModule' {
    const myModule: MyModule
    export = myModule
}
```

Maybe adding a triple slash directing to myFile:

myFile.ts

```
/// <reference path="./myModule.d.ts" />
import * as myModule from './myModule'

function doesSomething(input: string) {
    return myModule[input]
}
```

That doesn't really change anything though.

Comment: export your interface and try again

Comment: @Hey24sheep doesn't seem to change anything

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're only expecting to call `doesSomething` with the strings whose values are the same as the names of`myModule`, you could do something like

```
import * as myModule from './myModule';

type ModuleType = typeof myModule;

function doesSomething<K extends keyof ModuleType>(input: K): ModuleType[K] {
    return myModule[input]
}
```

and you'll have a more accurate return type that reflects the type `foo`, `bar`, etc.

Comment: This answers the question and gets rid of the error message, so accepted. However, I actually need to access a property on foo/bar and now I have new error to solve which is "Property 'myProperty' does not exist on type 'typeof "./myModule"[K]'. Also, any file that imports myModule is going to need the same type definition which would optimally be supplied with myModule.

Comment: Yes, anyone who wants this will need some exported type that describes the shape of the module.You can write an interface that the module satisfies instead, and use that in place of `ModuleType`. I'm not sure why you're having other problems accessing properties once you've called `doesSomething("foo")` though.

Comment: The error regarding accessing 'myProperty' was because not all of the exports on myModule actually have 'myProperty' --- so ya, that error is the desired behavior and reaffirms my decision to move to typescript in the first place. I think an interface is the right approach long term, but the accepted answer is a good temp solution to help get through compiler errors. Thanks.

Comment: There's also this weird hack:

`function doesSomething<K extends keyof ModuleType>(input: K | string) {
        return input in myModule ? myModule[input as K] : undefined;
    }`